# Place text at margin, breaking a list (flexibility to work before items required)

Tags: lists, margins, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

Within a list environment, enumerate say, how can I place some text, between or before items.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

    % Text here to be at margin

    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I am aware of the start/resume functionality offered by `enumitem`, however, I need to be able to do this *before* any items are called (i.e. before First item). I require this as part of a separate command that I am preparing which needs flexibility to be called anywhere within the list.

Ideally, say, if there was a command like `\atMargin{Here is the text}` which just printed the text at the margin, that would solve the problem.

My current solution involves introducing a phantom item and then attempting to negate the space from this, but of course is suboptimal:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

    \item[] \vspace{-1cm}

    \end{enumerate}

Text at margin

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The easy solution is to put the text before starting enumerate.  You can add extra paragrpahs after an \item, but nothing can come before the first \item.

Comment: Can elaborate if required, but not compatible with the command that I need to make, which needs to be able to invoked anywhere within a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows how to add full width text after an `\item`.  (Idea stolen from exam class.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\noindent Text at margin

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    
\hspace*{-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}%
\parbox{\textwidth}{Text at Margin}

    \item Second item
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

I don't see the point, but you can always add a phantom `\item[]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[]\hspace*{-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}%
\parbox{\textwidth}{Text at Margin}

    \item First item
    
\item[]\hspace*{-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}%
\parbox{\textwidth}{Text at Margin}

    \item Second item
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\hspace*{-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname}%
      \parbox{\textwidth}{Text at Margin}`

Works well, except for not before the first \item as needed. Anyway that this can be modified as required?

Need a flexible single solution that can be called anywhere within the list

Comment: All good, will revert to this if no other solution:

The point is that I want to put headings within the list (for different difficulty levels), and so need the ability to call this command flexibly, e.g.

Level 1:
- q1
- q2

Level 2:
- q1
- q2

At the moment just using resume functions on lists

Comment: You might check out the outlines package (check spelling).  It uses \1., \2, etc. to select the depth using a single environment for all 4 layers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want it at the level of the first item:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\reversemarginpar %left side for better view
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

    \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\marginpar{Text here to be at margin}}

    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I meant to say right of the margin, not in the margin, apologies. Any possible amendments to above?

Answer (score -1):

```
\RaggedRight {\tabitem text. 
\newline \tabitem text. 
\newline \tabitem text.
```

Insert whatever text you need.

```
\newline \tabitem text.}
 
& \RaggedRight{\tabitem text.
```

`tabitem` can be used to prepare the list. So, text can be inserted anywhere.

```
 \newline \tabitem text.}
```

Comment: Isn't this for within a table? This is just a standard enumerate list

Comment: This option works well for his necessities.